# javascript setCookie expiration wrong or ignored by browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

Question about cookie expiration.

I'm trying the setCookie from w3schools.com

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  console.log(expires);
}
```

when I try (note: today 2020-03-17...)

```
setCookie("test_cookie", "hello world", 363);
```

chrome dev says cookie

> expires 2020-03-24....

but console.log I added says

> expires=Wed, 15 Mar 2021

same thing happens with toGMTString

seems the browser ignores expires, and does 7 days...

so how to really set a cookie expiring in 1 month or 1 year ???